# Using scipy.stats library or another method to generate data follows a distribution in a specific boundary

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to sample with `scipy.stats` library, using an upper and a lower boundary for the sampled data. I am interested to use `scipy.stats.lognorm` and `scipy.stats.expon` and set a constrain `(low<=x<=up)` on the limits of generated data points and also estimate `logp` with considering these limits. For instance, I can not do

```
LogNormal=scipy.stats.lognorm(q=[0,5],scale=[0.25],loc=0.0) #q:upper and lower limits, scale=sigma, loc=mean
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 739, in __call__
    return self.freeze(*args, **kwds)
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 736, in freeze
    return rv_frozen(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 434, in __init__
    shapes, _, _ = self.dist._parse_args(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: _parse_args() got an unexpected keyword argument 'q'
```

The documentation is a bit confusing, which one is `sigma` and which input parameter is `mean`? Could anybody give an example, how they should be set with boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your implementation

1, your pdf can not be evaluated at x=0

2, `-log(1./sqrt(2*pi)/self.sigma*exp(-0.5*((log(value)-self.mu)/self.sigma)**2))` should be: `-log(1./sqrt(2*pi)/self.sigma/value*exp(-0.5*((log(value)-self.mu)/self.sigma)**2))`

(And there may be more)

Another consideration is that you may want to keep the parameterization the same as `scipy` to avoid future confusion.

Therefore, a minimal implementation:

```
In [112]:
import scipy.stats as ss
import scipy.optimize as so
import numpy as np

class bounded_distr(object):
    def __init__(self, parent_dist):
        self.parent = parent_dist
    def bnd_lpdf(self, x, limits=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if limits and np.diff(limits)<=0:
            return -np.inf #nan may be better idea
        else:
            _v = -log(self.parent.pdf(x, *args, **kwargs))
            _v[x<=limits[0]] = -np.inf
            _v[x>=limits[1]] = -np.inf
            return _v
    def bnd_cdf(self, x, limits=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if limits and np.diff(limits)<=0:
            return 0 #nan may be better idea
        elif limits:
            _v1 = self.parent.cdf(x, *args, **kwargs)
            _v2 = self.parent.cdf(limits[0], *args, **kwargs)
            _v3 = self.parent.cdf(limits[1], *args, **kwargs)
            _v4 = (_v1-_v2)/(_v3-_v2)
            _v4[_v4<0] = np.nan
            _v4[_v4>1] = np.nan
            return _v4
        else:
            return self.parent.cdf(x, *args, **kwargs)
    def bnd_rvs(self, size, limits=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if limits and np.diff(limits)<=0:
            return np.repeat(np.nan, size) #nan may be better idea
        elif limits:
            low, high = limits
            rnd_cdf = np.random.uniform(self.parent.cdf(x=low, *args, **kwargs),
                                        self.parent.cdf(x=high, *args, **kwargs),
                                        size=size)
            return self.parent.ppf(q=rnd_cdf, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.parent.rvs(size=size, *args, **kwargs)
In [113]:

bnd_logn = bounded_distr(ss.lognorm)
In [114]:

bnd_logn.bnd_rvs(10, limits=(0.1, 0.9), s=1, loc=0)
Out[114]:
array([ 0.23167598,  0.43185726,  0.34763109,  0.71020467,  0.5216074 ,
        0.60883528,  0.34353607,  0.84530444,  0.64145739,  0.82082447])
In [115]:

bnd_logn.bnd_lpdf(np.linspace(0,1,10), limits=(0.1, 0.9), s=1, loc=0)
Out[115]:
array([        inf,  1.13561188,  0.54598554,  0.42380072,  0.43681222,
        0.50389845,  0.5956744 ,  0.69920358,  0.80809192,  0.91893853])
In [116]:

bnd_logn.bnd_cdf(np.linspace(0,1,10), limits=(0.1, 0.9), s=1, loc=0)
Out[116]:
array([        nan,  0.00749028,  0.12434152,  0.28010562,  0.44267888,
        0.59832448,  0.74188947,  0.87201574,  0.98899161,         nan])
```

Comment: when I try to estimate logpdf in a given limit, it could not return -in. For instance this `bounded_distr(ss.expon).bnd_lpdf(5.6e12, limits=(1e13, 1e16), scale=1e15)` gives `34.544376394910685`. It could not recognize the limits.

Comment: Sorry, forget to add that in the `bnd_lpdf` method. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally write two classes of prior, which can also sample data based on the given distribution in the given limits. I used the [inverse sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) method to sample data. My classes are given as following:

```
import os, sys
import logging
import scipy.stats
from numpy import exp, sqrt, log, isfinite, inf, pi
import scipy.special
import scipy.optimize
class LogPrior(object):
    def eval(self, value):
        return 0.
    def __call__(self, value):
        return self.eval(value)
    def sample(self, n=None):
        """ Sample from this prior. The returned array axis=0 is the
            sample axis.

            Parameters
            ----------
            n : int (optional)
                Number of samples to draw
        """
        raise ValueError("Cannot sample from a LogPrior object.")
    def __str__(self):
        return "<LogPrior>"
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

**Update:** The class of **Lognormal distribution**:

```
class LognormalPrior(LogPrior):
    """
    Log-normal log-likelihood.

    Distribution of any random variable whose logarithm is normally
    distributed. A variable might be modeled as log-normal if it can
    be thought of as the multiplicative product of many small
    independent factors.

    .. math::
        f(x \mid \mu, \tau) = \sqrt{\frac{\tau}{2\pi}}\frac{
        \exp\left\{ -\frac{\tau}{2} (\ln(x)-\mu)^2 \right\}}{x}

    :Parameters:
      - `x` : x > 0
      - `mu` : Location parameter.
      - `tau` : Scale parameter (tau > 0).

    .. note::

       :math:`E(X)=e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2\tau}}`
       :math:`Var(X)=(e^{1/\tau}-1)e^{2\mu+\frac{1}{\tau}}`

    """
    def __init__(self, mu, tau, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LognormalPrior, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mu = mu
        self.tau = tau
        self.mean = exp(mu + 1./(2*tau))
        self.median = exp(mu)
        self.mode = exp(mu - 1./tau)
        self.variance = (exp(1./tau) - 1) * exp(2*mu + 1./tau)
        self.sigma=1./sqrt(tau)
    def logp(self, value, limits=None):
        if limits:
           lower,upper=limits
           """Log of lognormal prior probability with hard limits."""
           if value >= lower and value <= upper:
              return -log(1./sqrt(2*pi)/value/self.sigma*exp(-0.5*((log(value)-self.mu)/self.sigma)**2))
           else:
              return -inf           
        else:
           """Log of normal prior probability."""
           return -log(1./sqrt(2*pi)/value/self.sigma*exp(-0.5*((log(value)-self.mu)/self.sigma)**2))
    #Cumulative distribution function of lognormal distribution 
    def cdf(self, value):
       if not isinstance(value, float):
          res=np.empty_like(value)
          for i in range(res.shape[0]):
              if value[i]==0.0:
                 res[i]=0.0
              else:
                 res[i]=0.5+0.5*scipy.special.erf((log(value[i])-self.mu)/(sqrt(2)*self.sigma))
          return res
       else:
          if value==0.0:
             return 0.0
          else:
             return 0.5+0.5*scipy.special.erf((log(value)-self.mu)/(sqrt(2)*self.sigma))

    #sampling data with the given distribution    
    def sample(self, n, limits=None):
        res=np.empty(n)
        if limits:
           lower,upper=limits 
           j=0
           while (j<n):
               def f(x):
           return self.cdf(x)-np.random.uniform(low=0,high=1,size=1)
           s=scipy.optimize.brenth(f,0,20)
           if s >= lower and s <= upper:
          res[j]=s
              j+=1
    else:
       r=np.random.uniform(low=0,high=1,size=n)
       for j in range(n):
               def f(x):
           return self.cdf(x)-r[j]
           s=scipy.optimize.brenth(f,0,20)
           res[j]=s
        return res
```

The class of **Exponential distribution**

```
class ExponentialPrior(LogPrior):
    """
    Exponential distribution

    Parameters
    ----------
    lam : float
        lam > 0
        rate or inverse scale
    """
    def __init__(self, lam, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExponentialPrior, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.lam = lam
        self.mean = 1. / lam
        self.median = self.mean * log(2)
        self.mode = 0
        self.variance = lam ** -2
    def logp(self, value, limits=None):
        if limits:
           lower,upper=limits
           """Log of lognormal prior probability with hard limits."""
           if value >= lower and value <= upper:
          return -log(self.lam)+self.lam*value
           else:
              return -inf
        else:
              """Log of normal prior probability."""
              return -log(self.lam)+self.lam*value
    def cdf(self, value):
        """Cumulative distribution function lognormal function""" 
        return (1-exp(-self.lam*value))
    #sampling data with the given distribution    
    def sample(self, n, limits=None):
        res=np.empty(n)
        if limits:
           lower,upper=limits 
           j=0
           while (j<n):
               def f(x):
           return self.cdf(x)-np.random.uniform(low=0,high=1,size=1)
           s=scipy.optimize.brenth(f,0,100)
           if s >= lower and s <= upper:
          res[j]=s
              j+=1
    else:
       r=np.random.uniform(low=0,high=1,size=n)
       for j in range(n):
               def f(x):
           return self.cdf(x)-r[j]
           s=scipy.optimize.brenth(f,0,100)
           res[j]=s
        return res
```

Comment: These are certainly informative but they in fact provide more info about the OP rather than answering it. You would want to edit the OP and incorporate these lines of code. Cheers!

Comment: @CTZhu Thank you for pointing out the couple of mistakes I had in my answer. However, I updated my answer. I found it very hard to set boundaries for sampling the data with `scipy.stats` library, it was my motivation to write my own class.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import lognorm

mean = 4.0 # Geometric mean == median
standard_deviation = 2.0 # Geometric standard deviation
sigma = np.log(standard_deviation) # Standard deviation of log(X)
x = np.linspace(0.1, 25, num=400) # values for x-axis
pdf = lognorm.pdf(x, sigma, loc=0, scale=mean) # probability distribution
plt.plot(x,pdf)
plt.show()
```

[image: Lognormal Plot]

Comment: I want to generate random number in a specific boundary of lognormal distribution. I know I can plot it in specific limits.